# MongoDB merge int arrays in one result

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregation result

```js
[
  {
    "ids": [1,100]
  },
  {
    "ids": [200, 100, 3]
  }
]
```

I want to merge them as one result like this:

```js
[
    1,
    200,
    100,
    3
]
```

I have tried group but the result not like I want:

```js
{
    $group: {
        _id: 1,
        merged: {
            $push: "$ids"
        }
    }
}

result:
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "merged": [
      [1, 100],
      [200, 100, 3]
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Query

- we dont have `$concat` accumulator
- you can do it with `$unwind` , `$group` `$addToSet`
  (null or 1 its the same, as long each member is grouped with same key, null is more common)
- or you could do it with `$push` and `$reduce` `$union`
- here is the first approach looks easier

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49ad)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": {"path": "$ids"}},
  {"$group": {"_id": null, "ids": {"$addToSet": "$ids"}}},
  {"$unset": ["_id"]}])
```

Comment: Good one, thank you